# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // mSelectText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

   LinkList link = new LinkList();
    ArrayList<String> items= null;
    try {
        items = link.ImageLink();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, items));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(gridviewOnItemClickListener);
}
private GridView.OnItemClickListener gridviewOnItemClickListener = new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // выводим номер позиции
       // mSelectText.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    }
};
```

}

> 06-10 14:24:21.748 1154-1154/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6257288)
>   06-10 14:24:21.748 1154-1154/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lubomurv3/com.example.lubomurv3.MainActivity}:android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                        at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                     Caused by:   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
>                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
>                                                        at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
>                                                        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
>                                                        at com.example.lubomurv3.LinkList.readJsonFromUrl(LinkList.java:30)
>                                                        at com.example.lubomurv3.LinkList.ImageLink(LinkList.java:47)
>                                                        at com.example.lubomurv3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)   
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь ошибка `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`, то есть подключение к интернету из главного потока. Выполните подключение из другого потока, используя, например, `AsyncTask`.